# (jQuery/Selectors) select element after a specified class

Tags: jquery

i am trying to use the plugin [infinite scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

it requires the selector for the next page link. i suppose that if the navigation is as follows,

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="next">page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

i can use `"a.next"` as the selector for the next page. but what happens if my page nav markup is as follows, without the `.next` class

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">page 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

how can i select the page 2 link assuming `.active` signifies the current page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select the node next to .active, you can use the next() function:

```
$('.active').next();
```

But why not add a prev/next list item that's always there?

Comment: the next() method "Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector."  There are no immediate siblings of the active class

Comment: Yes it. It looks at the element and not at the class

Comment: It's the right idea, though. Perhaps something like $('.active').parent().next().children().first() (Yeah, kind of long and complicated, but it works).

Comment: @John Hartsock The immediate siblings of the active class are the other <li> nodes. My example works, I've put together a snippet to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/QdV7q/ (don't be surprised by the alerts ;) )

Comment: @Peter - Your jsFiddle changes the OP's HTML. Take a closer look. The `.active` class is on an `<a>` element *inside* the `<li>`. Yours placed `.active` directly on the `<li>`.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that. Seems like Ryan got it right the first time!

Comment: oh ya, i forgot abt the prev/next link

Answer (score 2):

`$("li:has(.active) + li a")` will do the job. E.g.

```
alert($("li:has(.active) + li a").text());
```

Comment: i happen to feel that since i am able to use **prev/next** links it is straight forward but i agree that if i am constraint to having `.active` class this maybe better ... hmm but will that selector select **all** siblings rather than the **single next** link?

Comment: This solution works on the example you had in the OP. If you were to have more than one anchor in the `LI` and needed to target the first anchor in the next `LI`, then you would have to add `:first` to the statement. E.g. `$("li:has(.active) + li a:first").text();`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.active').parent().next().children().eq(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a unique `id` to your `<a>` tags in order to be able to use the plugin.

Cheers,