# Add next item and item after next to current collection

Tags: jquery, dom

Imagine the following HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="elem1"></div>
    <div class="helperBtn"></div>
    <div class="helperBtn"></div>

    <div id="elem2"></div>
    <div class="helperBtn"></div>
    <div class="helperBtn"></div>

    <div id="elem3"></div>
    <div class="helperBtn"></div>
    <div class="helperBtn"></div>
</div>
```

How does one select `elem2` and both following `div.helperBtn`'s ?
I've tried something like this: `$('#elem2').add(':next')` but couldn't get any working solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you want to add your stuff at posn `elem2` or in the `helperbtn`s ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, you can use [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) with [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/):

```
var elements = $("#elem2").nextUntil("#elem3").addBack();
```

The above will match all the elements between `#elem2` and `#elem3`, then add `#elem2` back into the set. The resulting jQuery object will contain three elements.

**EDIT:** I see legitimate concern in another answer about this solution being hardcoded. That's true, but it can easily be modified so you only have to specify the first element:

```
var elements = $("#elem2").nextUntil(":not(.helperBtn)").addBack();
```

Comment: Superb solution! Thanks for that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: +1 Perfect! Now it's perfect! You can also implement a `$(".parent").each` loop to go over all `#elem1`, `#elem2` and `#elem3` like I did below

Answer (score 1):

This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195378/jquery-selectors-select-element-after-a-specified-class) question. (Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826089/jquery-select-first-element-that-has-a-certain-class-after-this))

But what is most easy is given a 'parent' class and then adding the children like so:

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="parent" id="elem1"></div>
    <div class="helperBtn">helper 1.1</div>
    <div class="helperBtn">helper 1.2</div>

    <div class="parent" id="elem2"></div>
    <div class="helperBtn">helper 2.1</div>
    <div class="helperBtn">helper 2.2</div>

    <div class="parent" id="elem3"></div>
    <div class="helperBtn">helper 3.1</div>
    <div class="helperBtn">helper 3.2</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery example**

```
current = $('.parent').next();

alert(current.text()); //Selects first helperBtn

current = current.next();

alert(current.text()); //Selects second helperBtn
```

You can find this implementation in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zc9Eq/).

**jQuery implementation**

```
$(".parent").each(function()
{
    current = $(this).next();
    alert(current.text()); //Selects first helperBtn

    current = current.next();
    alert(current.text()); //Selects second helperBtn               
});
```

Where a demo can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QkCjr/).

That should help you out! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I'll use Frederic Hamidis solution for now, looks a little bit better :P

Comment: @peipst9lker: Whatever you want. Frederic's solution is hardcoded though, mine is not. But whatever you prefer you should do.

Comment: He just editet his code, allthough in this case I can use hardcoded class names.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution but does work.

```
$elem2 = $("#elem2");
$elemhelperButton = $elem2.next();
$elem2 = $elem2.add($elemhelperButton);
$elem2 = $elem2.add($elemhelperButton.next());

$elem2.click(function () {
  alert("hi there");
});
```